# regex, anything but phrase a or phrase b, as part of a larger expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, php-7

I'm trying to build a function to drop vars in a string
for example

> Hi, My name is {!first_name!}
>    and my family name is {!last_name!},
>    To
>   sum it up, my name is {!full_name!}.
>    I am a {!job_title!}.
>    To use my
>   function just write your vars like this @{!code!}

and my regular expression

```
/(@?)(\{\!\s*([^\{\!\!\}]*)\s*\!\})/Uis
```

my problem is that if I have more then one character as the start or end of the var, then `[^x]` does not work like expected
so how can I have an expression like this

```
/(@?)(\{\!\s*(**anything but {! or !}**)\s*\!\})/Uis
```

Or maybe their is a better approach altogether.

Thank you.

edit:
Here is my full function [click here](https://gist.github.com/MordiSacks/a67fc725ae1b9bc1d9844dd6583ad3f0)
as it is now, it works, but if I want to do something like this.

`echo dropVars($str, $vars, ['{!','!}']);` 
It will fail (actually it will not, but I hope you get my point)

Comment: I am a bit confused about your requirements, are you after `(@)?(\{\!\s*(?!(?:\{\!|\!\}))\S*\!\})` ? See [here](https://regex101.com/r/OrG0sg/2).

Comment: `[^x]` just matches a single character at a time, it doesn't match sequences. Use a negative lookahead to prevent matching a sequence.

Comment: @Stanzi1791 How would use use `sprintf()` to substitute by name rather than positionally?

Comment: Which phrase do you want to ignore? Maybe `(@?)(?:\{!\s*(?!first_name)(.*)\s*\!\})` is something you're looking for

Comment: There are many existing template libraries for PHP, I suggest you use one of them instead of trying to roll your own.

Comment: @Stanzi1791 It seems obvious from the example that he wants to replace `{!first_name!}` with a `first_name` variable, `{!last_name!}` with a `last_name` variable, etc. How would you do that with `sprintf()` if the order of the variables can change?

Comment: @UnbearableLightness your expression seems to work, but it leaves me with `{!code!}` and I want to be left with `code`

Comment: Try with alternation `(\{\!\s*(?!(?:\{\!|\!\}))\S*\!\})|(@)\{\!([^!]+)\!\}` [here](https://regex101.com/r/OrG0sg/3).

Comment: Try [`'~(@?)({!\s*((?:(?!{!|!}).)*?)\s*!})~'is`](https://regex101.com/r/4Su2GJ/1). Do not use `U` modifier with this pattern.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks! thats what I was looking for.

Comment: Nice one Wiktor, you should post it as an answer, I'll upvote it.

Comment: @Barmar: with `sprintf` you can't use names but you can specify which variable you want in the format using a number and a `$` in the placeholder: `printf('%2$s %1$s %2$s %2$s', 'foo', 'bar');`. But for this kind of task `strtr` with an associative array is better imo.

Comment: Maybe you should post an answer showing what you're recommending.

Comment: @phper I posted with explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<?php
$input = "Hi, My name is {!first_name!}
          and my family name is {!last_name!},
          To sum it up, my name is {!full_name!}.
          I am a {!job_title!}.
          To use my function just write your vars like this @{!code!}";

preg_match_all('/@?\{\!\s*([^{!}]*)\s*\!\}/mi', $input, $matches);

print_r($matches);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => {!first_name!}
            [1] => {!last_name!}
            [2] => {!full_name!}
            [3] => {!job_title!}
            [4] => @{!code!}
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => first_name
            [1] => last_name
            [2] => full_name
            [3] => job_title
            [4] => code
        )

)
```

I changed your regex to be a little simpler and I'm capturing only the text part in between the exclamations and curly brackets.  I removed the 'U' and 's' flags since I didn't think they were needed.  I added the 'm' flag to allow the pattern to match over multiple lines.

Here's another example that replaces each template variable with a corresponding value:

```
<?php
$input = "Hi, My name is {!first_name!}
and my family name is {!last_name!},
To sum it up, my name is {!full_name!}.
I am a {!job_title!}.
To use my function just write your vars like this @{!code!}";

$replacement_values = [
  "first_name" => "Billy",
  "last_name" => "Jean",
  "full_name" => "Ms. Billy Jean",
  "job_title" => "Lover",
  "code" => "vars",
];


$input = preg_replace_callback(
    '/@?\{\!\s*([^{!}]*)\s*\!\}/mi',
    function ($matches){
        global $replacement_values;
        return $replacement_values[$matches[1]];
    },
    $input
);


echo $input;
?>
```

Output:

```
Hi, My name is Billy
and my family name is Jean,
To sum it up, my name is Ms. Billy Jean.
I am a Lover.
To use my function just write your vars like this vars
```

Comment: Instead of the loop, you could use `preg_replace_callback()`.

Comment: @Barmar great point!  I have changed the code to use preg_replace_callback which should allow the code to replace everything in one regular expression run as opposed to doing it once for each possible value as I had previously.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
'~(@?)({!\s*((?:(?!{!|!}).)*?)\s*!})~is'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4Su2GJ/1)

**Details**

- `(@?)` - Group 1: an optional `@` char
- `({!\s*((?:(?!{!|!}).)*?)\s*!})` - Group 2:

  - `{!` - a `{!` substring
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `((?:(?!{!|!}).)*?)` - Group 3: any char, as few as possible, that does not start `{!` or `!}` substrings
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `!}`  - a literal substring.